# How does the Backbone.js url function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am fairly new to Backbone, I have been doing tutorials in order to understand Backbone better but I never could figure out how the url works that can be defined in the Models.

*url: '/todoItem'*

I came from a PHP environment and am used to static pages. What exactly is '/todoItem'?

Thank you.

Comment: I promise I'm not being snarky. I'd definitely recommend reading through Backbone's source to help you learn it. It isn't too long and I find it helps a lot to see how everything fits together.

Comment: Agreed. I think I will give it a read ;) thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backbone assumes a REST-style API where each model is a REST resource with it's own URL path. So you might be able to do things like:

- create a car resource with `POST /car`
- read a specific car resource with `GET /car/42`
- update a car specific resource with `PUT /car/42` and a JSON request body like `{"model": "Corolla"}`
- delete a specific car with `DELETE /car/42`

So normally for a model wants the URL to be `/car` if it's a new (not-yet-saved) model and `/car/42` otherwise. Thus the [default implementation from backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-64) is:

```
url: function() {
  var base = _.result(this, 'urlRoot') || _.result(this.collection, 'url') || urlError();
  if (this.isNew()) return base;
  return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) === '/' ? '' : '/') + encodeURIComponent(this.id);
},
```

So normally, all you need to do is change the `urlRoot` property and you are good to go if your API follows REST conventions.

```
var Car = Backbone.Model.extend({urlRoot: '/car'});
```

Comment: Peter, I still don't quite understand. What happens on that url? How does the information that is posted to the URL get inserted inside the database?

Comment: @IlyaKarnaukhov: You need some server-side code (possibly PHP, possibly something else, Backbone doesn't care) to handle the [GET/POST/PUT/... requests](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-174) and talk to the database. You might need to use [`emulateHTTP`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateHTTP) or [`emulateJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateJSON) depending on how the server works.

Comment: @IlyaKarnaukhov stack overflow is for specific questions. Backbone is extremely well documented and there a many many high-quality tutorials and demo projects. Start there. The basic architecture is a database, a web application on the server with some business logic to work with the database data, a RESTful API presented to the browser, and a backbone-based javascript single page application design in the browser.